# Change marker in a leaflet map with GeoJson data

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I build a web map with Leaflet and GeoJSON. I want to change the marker but the example of Leaflet site it doesn't help me, because it is for a local file. Any idea how to change it?

```
$.getJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vassilaros/3791204ca226d5b236b4cd3106ef23cf/raw/PicnicSites.geojson", function(data) { addDataToMap(data, map); });
```

and

```
function addDataToMap(data, map) {
                var dataLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
                    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                        var popupText = "Name: " + feature.properties.Name
                        + "<br>Location: " + feature.properties.place
                        + "<br><a href='" + feature.properties.url + "'>More info</a>";
                        layer.bindPopup(popupText); }
                });
                dataLayer.addTo(map);
            }
```

**EDIT:**

For examble I want to add the foolowing marker

```
var MyIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
```

and I want to add `{icon: greenIcon}` to my layer.
Were I have to add this line of code?

**EDIT2:**

I want to change this markers:
[image]

Comment: Which point do you want to replace with which?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet: how to use a custom marker on a geojson layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820267/leaflet-how-to-use-a-custom-marker-on-a-geojson-layer)

Comment: I think your json is not valid

Answer (score 2):

Just use the pointToLayer function

```
  var MyIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

  L.geoJson(data  ,{
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
      return L.marker(latlng,{icon: MyIcon});
    }
  }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: The poinToLayer maybe is the solution. I found this question close to mine.https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179912/leaflet-html-geojson-how-to-put-a-pop-up-on-a-geojson-point